# How combine 3 mysql queries together?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 different types of queries to retrieve data in same page. How will I combine altogether? The following is the query:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE ((day1sql >= now()))";
if($_GET!=""){
$mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['datepicker']);
if($mydate!=""){    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE ((day1 = '$mydate'))";  
}       
}
if($_GET!=""){
$city1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cityText']);
if($city1!=""){ 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE (city = $city1))";  
}       
}
```

datepicker is a calendar, users can get data according to date. And Have an dropdown menu, users can select city name. The first two queries is working fine. I am confused how to integrate the third query?

Comment: As stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [logical `OR` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) to combine your filter criteria:

```sql
SELECT * FROM general WHERE day1sql >= now() OR day1 = '$mydate' OR city = '$city1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE (day1sql >= now())";

if(isset($_GET['datepicker'])){
    $mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['datepicker']);
    $sql .= " AND (day1 = '$mydate')";         
}
if(isset($_GET['cityText'])){
    $city1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cityText']);
    $sql .= " AND (city = $city1)";  
}       

// execute $sql
```

We are appending the sql with AND conditions. I believe that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: It would be lot more helpful if you explain "not working". I mean, if you provide more details about what it is giving and what you were expecting, we might be able to suggest better solutions ! :)